# Decreasing the fortran run time by extra optimization flags

Tags: optimization, fortran

I have been trying to optimize my program for some time now. It has more than 100 subroutines. The optimization flags I have used so far with the Intel Fortran compiler are as follows.

```
Optimization flag Time of completion
-c                     0.190 hr
-O3                    0.185 hr
-fast                  0.155 hr
```

So, using the optimization flag "-fast" I was able to gain 18.42% speed. I was wondering are there any other optimization flag that I can try to make my program run even faster. Because right now, when I ran my program with just O2 flag for one of my problem, it took around 25 hours to finish. I really need to increase the computational efficiency.

I found the information about the "-fast" flag from https://support.scinet.utoronto.ca/wiki/images/7/77/Snug_techtalk_compiler.pdf

I am using the intel fortran 13.1 compiler in linux.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thank you so much.

Best Regards,

Jdbaba

Comment: Changed the title to "decreasing run time" (not "increasing") since that's what you're really asking. You may want to try the `-faster`, `-warp=11` or `-so_damn_fast_it_ends_before_it_starts` flags :-)

Comment: @ paxdiablo thank you for your reply and editing my post title. I will try to use the optimization flags you suggested and then will post if there is any speed gain. Do I use this optimization flags in addition to -fast or separately ?

Comment: @ paxdiablo When I tried to use the option -faster then it says ifort: command line warning #10006: ignoring unknown option '-faster'. The code I used is ifort *.for -c -faster and on the next line I used ifort *.o -o hello -faster. But it throws an warning. Did I do anything wrong ?

Comment: Did you do anything wrong? Yes! You didn't see the humour in my comment :-) I would have thought that was evident by the third flag but, like my wife, the vast majority of the planet doesn't understand my severely warped sense of humour. Sorry about that.

Comment: @ paxdiablo So all of those options given by you don't really exist, right ? I also thought the third one is not right, but since I am new to this I was bound to believe.

Comment: No, afraid not. Or, more correctly, they _may_ exist but it's unlikely (since I didn't write the compiler).

Comment: With all due respect to @paxdiablo I suggest OP consults the Intel Fortran compiler manual for further information on the availability and impact of compiler flags.  I suggest OP also consult Intel's publications on optimising Fortran programs. Oh, and don't forget to profile your application.

Comment: @ high performance mark Thank you for your reply. I didn't understand what you meant by profile your application.

Comment: Added what compiler you use. It was not clear to me to me all. Note other compilers use flags with e same name.

Comment: I used intel fortran 13.0 compiler on Linux.

Comment: Intel has a [reference guide](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/collateral/hpc/compilers/compiler_qrg12.pdf) on optimisation. Manual profiling is certainly insightful; additionally you can use `-opt-report`, `-guide` and `-par-report` to get detailed reports on what ifort can do with your code. Also useful are `-prof-gen` and `-prof-use` to use profiling data to further optimise programs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say which compiler you are using but imply Intel with your link. With Intel ifort you can try `-parallel` and obtain automatic parallelization.  Past some point the compiler will have done its best with your source code and further runtime decreases will require either improving bad coding decisions or algorithmic improvements, neither of which we have information from your question to offer specific suggestions.  "profiling" is identifying where your program spends its runtime.   There is no point in making subroutine A run ten times faster if the program only spends 1% of its runtime in subroutine A ... you will obtain very little overall improvement.  Better to work on the subroutines in which the program spends 80% or 50% or ... of its runtime.

Comment: Thank you M.S.B for your reply. Yes, you are correct. I used intel compiler. I will identify the subroutine in which the program spends more time. Is it possible to figure out this while compiling the code ? I will look into the code itself to figure out as well. Actually, these are not my own codes. I got the code from another source and I am trying to make it faster. Thanks.

Comment: Now you know what profiling is and why it is important.  No, you cannot profile without executing the code.  Intel offer the VTune tool for profiling, if you don't have that available you could use `gprof` which is widely available on Linux machines.

Comment: @ High Performance Mark , Which flag do I need to use for the program in order to use for Vtune tool. Actually, I have vtune on my computer but when I load the compiled program it always gives error. It says failed to finalize the result. I really didn't know how to start with Vtune.

Comment: As to learning VTune, start by reading the introductory documentation; Intel provide oodles of it and some of it is very good.  SO is not an appropriate place for me to give you a tutorial in VTune.